# Clearing sensitive information when running "git commit"

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on a file with a bunch of sensitive information (e.g. passwords).

I'm working with version control and finding it burdensome to erase these passwords every time I commit and push this file.

Is there any way I could write a script somewhere to clear all of this sensitive information when I run "git commit"?

In other words, if my file looks like this:

```
var password = "test123"
```

I'd like my file to look like this when I commit it:

```
var password = ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (and correct, really) advice is to keep those passwords elsewhere, e.g., read them out of a different, not-version-controlled, file (`~/.netrc` and so on).

That said, you could use a pre-commit hook to check for a password in the index<sup>1</sup> and abort the commit if present (this is again standard advice: don't modify things in pre-commit hooks, just tell the user that there's something not right, and stop).  Or, you could even have the pre-commit hook adjust the index so that the password is absent.

Note that the pre-commit hook can be bypassed by the user, so this is not foolproof, no matter how you set it up (as a verifier, or as a modifier).

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that the new commit will be made from the contents of the *index*, not that of the working directory.  For instance:

```
$ echo this is what will be committed > foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt                 # put current foo.txt into the index
$ echo the current contents are completely different > foo.txt
$ git commit -m 'demonstrate index vs work dir'
```

The version of `foo.txt` in the commit this creates reads "this is what will be committed", even though "the current contents are completely different" is what is in `foo.txt` if you look at it now.  To see what's actually in the index, use, e.g.:

```
$ git cat-file -p :0:foo.txt
```

See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for what `:0:foo.txt` means.